# How to subset a generated list as it works its way through iterations of tidyverse imap function?

Tags: r, list, matrix, tidyverse, subset

In the below simplified example code, using the tidyverse `imap()` function I'm trying to get the "Inflow" columns of the matrixes generated after the first matrix of the same sublist group to equal the "Outflow" columns of the immediately prior matrix generated in the same sublist group. By a "sublist group" I mean the "mat_One" and "mat_Two" in the `matList <- list(mat_One = c("Boy", "Cat"), mat_Two = c("Boy", "Bat"))` object defined at the top of the code. Please don't worry about the calculations in the "Due" and "Outflow" columns, they are placeholders.

I would like the output to look like this:

[image]

But as the code is currently drafted, and as I try to figure out how to subset the `matL` object bouncing around the `imap()` function, the output looks like the below which at least proves that `matL[[index - 1]]` correctly identifies the prior matrix in a sublist group. My question is, how do I further subset `matL[[index - 1]]` in order to extract only the "Outflow" column of that matrix so that it is inserted into the "Inflow" column of the subsequent matrix in that same sublist group?
[image]

I've fiddled with variations of `matL[[index - 1]][[3]]`, etc., but can't see how the `matL` list object looks for subsetting purposes as it bounces around `imap()`.

Code:

```
library(tidyverse)

matList <- list(mat_One = c("Boy", "Cat"), mat_Two = c("Boy", "Bat"))
allocate <- list(mat_One = c(0.6, 0.5, 0.4), mat_Two = c(0.4, 0.5, 0.6))
flowVector <- c(6, 5, 600) 
rates <- list(mat_One = 0.10, mat_Two = 0.20)

createBucketMap <- function() {
  imap(matList, \(matL, matL_name) {
    imap(matL, \(x, index) {
      alc <- allocate[[matL_name]]
      rate <- rates[[matL_name]]
      { # calculations section....
        Inflow <- if(index == 1){flowVector * alc} else {matL[[index - 1]]} # ???
        Due <- balVector * alc * rate
        Outflow <- Inflow
      }
      cbind(
        Inflow,
        Due,
        Outflow
      )
    }) |> set_names(matL)
  })
}
createBucketMap()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use `purrr::reduce` for the inner loop.

Note: I slightly adjusted your example. First, I added the `balVector` from one of your previous questions. Second, I use `Outflow <- 2 * Inflow`.

```r
library(purrr)

matList <- list(mat_One = c("Boy", "Cat"), mat_Two = c("Boy", "Bat"))
allocate <- list(mat_One = c(0.6, 0.5, 0.4), mat_Two = c(0.4, 0.5, 0.6))
flowVector <- c(6, 5, 600)
balVector <- c(1000, 900, 800)
rates <- list(mat_One = 0.10, mat_Two = 0.20)

createBucketMap <- function() {
  imap(matList, \(matL, matL_name) {
    reduce(matL, \(x, y) {
      alc <- allocate[[matL_name]]
      rate <- rates[[matL_name]]
      Inflow <- if (is.null(x)) {
        flowVector * alc
      } else {
        x[[length(x)]][, "Outflow"]
      }
      Due <- balVector * alc * rate
      Outflow <- 2 * Inflow
      c(x, list(cbind(
        Inflow,
        Due,
        Outflow
      )))
    }, .init = NULL) |>
      set_names(matL)
  })
}
createBucketMap()
#> $mat_One
#> $mat_One$Boy
#>      Inflow Due Outflow
#> [1,]    3.6  60     7.2
#> [2,]    2.5  45     5.0
#> [3,]  240.0  32   480.0
#> 
#> $mat_One$Cat
#>      Inflow Due Outflow
#> [1,]    7.2  60    14.4
#> [2,]    5.0  45    10.0
#> [3,]  480.0  32   960.0
#> 
#> 
#> $mat_Two
#> $mat_Two$Boy
#>      Inflow Due Outflow
#> [1,]    2.4  80     4.8
#> [2,]    2.5  90     5.0
#> [3,]  360.0  96   720.0
#> 
#> $mat_Two$Bat
#>      Inflow Due Outflow
#> [1,]    4.8  80     9.6
#> [2,]    5.0  90    10.0
#> [3,]  720.0  96  1440.0
```

Comment: To get me head around `reduce()`. `map()` applies a function to each element of a list/vector, performing element-wise transformations. The results of `map()` has the same length as the input and preserves the original structure. On the other hand, `reduce()` function is used for successively applying a binary function to the elements of a list/vector, combining them in a cumulative manner. It aggregates the elements into a single result by iteratively applying the function to each pair of elements and the accumulated value. The resulting value is a single-element vector.

Comment: Yup. In general we use `reduce` to reduce a list to a single value. But there are no restrictions on what's meant by a single value, i.e. in my code the returned final result or single value is a list. For me the most natural candidate for this kind of operation was `accumulate` but I did not get it to work for your example.

Comment: I have long and tortured 3-level nested for-loop code that produces the same output, I run in parallel until I decide which way to go. This is very elegant and concise. But the advantage of the for-loop is that it's easy to run the code line-by-line as you build calculations and test. I assume it's not possible to do the same with `map()`, `reduce()`, `accumulate()` (test line-by-line).

Comment: You can add a `browser()` statement inside `map()` or `reduce()`. But you are right. `for`-loops are easier to debug and I use them quite often now where in the past I tried to use `reduce`.